# Reference data that could or not exist in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, distinct, group-concat

I have this tables:

```
courses: id_course,name_course
users: id_user,nickname_user
teachers: id_teacher,id_course_teacher,id_user_teacher (it has a value 
just in case this teacher is in the table users)
```

I'm listing one course with a list of all the teachers in it (with an auxiliary table):

```
SELECT c.name_course,group_concat(DISTINCT t.name_teacher) AS teachers 
FROM courses c
LEFT JOIN teachers t ON t.id_course_teacher=c.id_course
WHERE c.id_course='1';
It shows: Course 1: Teacher 1, Teacher 2, Teacher 5.
```

Some of those teachers have a profile in another table `users` and I want to show also the nickname of the teacher if it exists:

```
Course 1: Teacher 1, Teacher 2 (nickname), Teacher 5.
```

I tried this but I can not make a reference of the nickname to the teacher:

```
SELECT name_course,group_concat(DISTINCT t.name_teacher) AS teachers,
                   group_concat(DISTINCT u.nickname_user) AS nickname 
FROM courses c
LEFT JOIN teachers t ON t.id_course_teacher=c.id_course,
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.id_user_teacher=u.id_user 
WHERE c.id_course='1';
The value of nickname is just "nickname", but I can not reference it 
to the teacher 2.
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I make a subquery inside the LEFT JOINS? I am a bit lost with that. Thank you.

**Solution by InoS Heo (full explaind in his comment)**

I just had to add this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(t.name_teacher, ':', IF(u.nickname_user IS NULL, 'NULL', u.nickname_user))) AS name_nick_map
```

So I have in $row['name_nick_map'] the information I want (teacher 1:null,teacher 2:nickname2,teacher5:null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your schema and data. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7af94/1
We highly appreciate if you post your data in sqlfiddle.

I think to match teacher name and nickname, you should get rid of `GROUP_CONCAT()`

just like this:

```
SELECT name_course, t.name_teacher AS teachers,
                   u.nickname_user AS nickname 
FROM courses c
LEFT JOIN teachers t ON t.id_course_teacher=c.id_course
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.id_user_teacher=u.id_user 
WHERE c.id_course='c1';

+-------------+----------+-------------+
| name_course | teachers | nickname    |
+-------------+----------+-------------+
| c_name1     | t1_name  | u1_nickname |
| c_name1     | t2_name  | u2_nickname |
| c_name1     | t3_name  | NULL        |
+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

Assuming many to many relationship, I guess your db design is not NORMALIZED.

when teacher and course has many to many relationship, `teacher_to_course` table is required.

```
courses_to_teachers(id_course, id_teacher)

SELECT name_course, t.name_teacher AS teachers,
               u.nickname_user AS nickname 
FROM courses c
LEFT JOIN course_to_teachers ct ON c.id_course = ct.id_course
LEFT JOIN teachers t ON t.id_teacher = ct.id_teacher
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.id_user_teacher=u.id_user 
WHERE c.id_course='c1';
```

### UPDATE

> "I show the course with php, so could be possible to create an array array[t1_name=>u1_nickname, t2_name=>u2_nickname, etc...)?"

means, you are using `GROUP_CONCAT()` to make such array easier? I think it can be made without `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Anyway, if you need `GROUP_CONCAT()` why don't you try this? (you can test here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7af94/24/0)

```
SELECT name_course, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t.name_teacher, ':', IF(u.nickname_user IS NULL, 'NULL', u.nickname_user))) AS name_nick_map
FROM courses c
LEFT JOIN teachers t ON t.id_course_teacher=c.id_course
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.id_user_teacher=u.id_user 
WHERE c.id_course='c1'
GROUP BY name_course;
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| name_course | name_nick_map                                        |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| c_name1     | t1_name:u1_nickname,t2_name:u2_nickname,t3_name:NULL |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, `"t3_name:NULL"` represents `"t3_name has no nickname"`

**making array**

I wonder if you are asking this code. With following query and result.

```
SELECT name_course, t.name_teacher AS teacher, u.nickname_user AS nickname 
FROM courses c
LEFT JOIN teachers t ON t.id_course_teacher=c.id_course
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.id_user_teacher=u.id_user 
WHERE c.id_course='c1';
+-------------+----------+-------------+
| name_course | teacher  | nickname    |
+-------------+----------+-------------+
| c_name1     | t1_name  | u1_nickname |
| c_name1     | t2_name  | u2_nickname |
| c_name1     | t3_name  | NULL        |
+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

to make array.

```
$query = "SELECT ....";

$result = mysqli_query($query);

// error handling omitted

$CONTAINER = Array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $CONTAINER[$row['teacher']] = $row['nickname']; 
}

print_r($CONTAINER);

mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Probably `print_r($CONTAINER)` will produce something like `"array[t1_name=>u1_nickname, t2_name=>u2_nickname, etc...)"`

Comment: Yes, I have normalized the db, I just wrote it like that to make it more simple (I also use many other tables) :) The problem is that when I execute your second query, I  only get one row: name_course (1) | teachers (t1_name,t2_name,t3_name) | nickname (NULL). I show the course with php, so could be possible to create an array $array[t1_name=>u1_nickname, t2_name=>u2_nickname, etc...); ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: [http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c743/2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c743/2) Here I get 3 rows, but in my script only one, but with all data. Otherwise I will make another query to show only that information, but I just was wondering if I could do that only with one query. (The big query shows much more information, and the teachers with nickname is only a little part).

Comment: Great...!!! I used your first solution GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t.name_teacher...., but I added the DISTINCT: GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(t.name_teacher...  The second option of the array is not necessary ;) Thank you again a lot.. and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your query, if you execute it right you get the teachers name grouped as you wished:

```
SELECT name_course,group_concat(DISTINCT t.name_teacher) AS teachers,
                   group_concat(DISTINCT u.nickname_user) AS nicknames
FROM courses c
LEFT JOIN teachers t ON t.id_course_teacher=c.id_course
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.id_user_teacher=u.id_user 
WHERE c.id_course='1';
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero fue un error mio al escribir :)